# Get azure deadletter information and save into cosmos db

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core

In a project, my requirement is to get count of  azure deadletter. If the count is greater than 0 then I have to get details of every dead letter message like description or reason of dead letter and save into cosmos db.
To get dead letter count I am using code:

```
NamespaceManager namespaceManager=Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(sbConnectionString);    
var abc = namespaceManager.GetQueue("").MessageCountDetails;        
var deadLetterCount = messageDetails.DeadLetterMessageCount;
```

and save into  cosmos db, code is:

```
 DocumentDBModel objItem = new DocumentDBModel();    
                objItem.DeadLetterReason = "TestReason";    
                objItem.DeadLetterDescription = "TestDescription";   
                objItem.DeadLetterDate = DateTime.Now;    
                objItem.Body = "TestBody";    
                DbSettings objSettings = new DbSettings();    
                objSettings.Uri = "";    
                objSettings.Key = "";    
                objSettings.DatabaseId = "TestDB";    
                objSettings.Collection = "TestCollection";        
                DocumentDBRepository<DocumentDBModel> abc = new  
       DocumentDBRepository<DocumentDBModel>(objSettings);    
                abc.CreateAsync(objItem).Wait();
```

But when I run above code, I am getting exception in line:

```
var abc = namespaceManager.GetQueue("").MessageCountDetails;    


<b> Method not found: 'Void System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer..ctor(System.Type, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Type>, Int32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Runtime.Serialization.IDataContractSurrogate)'.
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingDescriptionSerializer`1.CreateSerializer[T]()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingDescriptionSerializer`1..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1..ctor(TrackingContext trackingContext, IResourceDescription[] collectionDescriptions, String[] collectionResourceNames, IEnumerable`1 managementAddresses, NamespaceManagerSettings settings, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.OnBeginGetQueue(String path, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.GetQueue(String path)
   at WebApplication2.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() </b>
```

Please suggest what can be the reason for this issue.
- List item

Comment: What's the version for [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) in your web application? Are you creating the net core web application, what is the target framework?

Comment: I am using WIndowsAzure.ServiceBus version  2.1.0   and Framework is ASP.Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) notes as follows:

> Please note that this package requires .Net Framework 4.5.2 Full Profile.

Moreover, I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned when using `WIndowsAzure.ServiceBus 2.1.0`. Also, I have checked the other versions, but failed in the end.

[image]

For NetCore 2.0, you could leverage the [.NET Standard client library for Azure Service Bus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet) and reference the package [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/). For retrieving the dead letter queues, you could follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/DeadletterQueue).

> my requirement is to get count of azure deadletter. If the count is greater than 0 then I have to get details of every dead letter message like description or reason of dead letter and save into cosmos db.

I noticed that you handle this processing within a WebAPI endpoint. I would recommend you register the `MessageReceiver.RegisterMessageHandler` callback mentioned under [DeadletterQueue/Program.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/DeadletterQueue/Program.cs), then implement it as the background task in .NET Core 2.x. Details you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/).

Additionally, you could distribute this processing out from your web application. And you could leverage [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to trigger your servicebus deadletter queue (e.g. the deadletter queue name for a specific queue would look like: `$"{your-queue-name}/$DeadLetterQueue"`) and use the DocumentDB binding to save deadletter queue information into your cosmos db. Details, you could refer to [How to use Azure Service Bus with the WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus) and [Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I will try your suggestions.